# Opencart custom category type

Tags: opencart, e-commerce

I'm working in an online store and I faced 2 problems with opencart.

1. I need to add custom category type like, Character, Movie.

So, one specific character, movie could be in various products. I want the character,movie to behave like categories, so when the customer clicked in the name, it would show all the products from that character,movie.

In Wordpress that would be really easy to do with Custom Post Types and Custom Taxonomy, but in Opencart I just can't find where to edit to get those modifications. (Wordpress is not an option because the client wants Opencart).

2. Is there any way to set url structure like this ?

Product/product-name
Category/category-name

Answer (score 0):

1. Opencart admin panel provides category feature. You can use the category feature to add more categories and you can assign products into multiple categories which is what you are looking for. You don't need any additional modifications for this.
2. Opencart provides a feature 'SEO URL' for every product in the admin panel. So you should read the docs or google it on how to use SEO URLs for the requirement you are trying to obtain.

Comment: thanks for your help bro , but i dont need to add my characters and series names in categories, thats why i need separate place to add my characters and series. just like manufacture .

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use tags in products page. It will solve your problem.
2. Use SEO URL option. Google it . you can get it.

Comment: Thanks for your help bro. i need to done on page seo for each Character, Movie. so each Character need front end page just like manufacture